# Exe built with cx_freeze produces "module not found" errors for required package

Tags: python, module, python-3.6, cx-freeze

I made a twitter bot using Python which uses the tweepy module. I then converted the Python file into an .exe file using cx_Freeze, following [these](https://regilanj.wordpress.com/2017/06/07/py-to-exe-in-python-3-6-1/comment-page-1/#comment-57) instructions. If I run the program in Powershell as the Python file it all works but when I try to run the .exe file in command prompt I get the error below:

```
 Traceback (most recent call last):
 File "C:\Python36\lib\site-packages\cx_Freeze\initscripts\__startup__.py", 
 line 14, in run module.run()
 File "C:\Python36\lib\site-packages\cx_Freeze\initscripts\Console.py", line 
 26, in run
exec(code, m.__dict__)
File "twitterbot_retweet_recent_tweets_2.py", line 1, in <module>
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'tweepy'
```

I've already tried uninstalling and reinstalling tweepy again but I keep on getting the same error. Does anyone know how to fix this?

Comment: I'm not familiar with cx_Freeze but just a stab here -- Did you reference the tweepy package properly in your setup.py file?

Comment: @DougCoburn No. In the setup.py file all I have for the packages is:                     packages = ["idna"]
options = {
    'build_exe': {

        'packages':packages,
    },

Comment: @DougCoburn Would I have to somehow add it in?

Comment: I'd give it a try: http://cx-freeze.readthedocs.io/en/latest/distutils.html

Comment: @DougCoburn Sorry I'm not entirely sure of the info on the link. Should I just write packages = ["idna", "tweepy"] instead of packages = ["idna"]?

Comment: That seems right, did it work?

Comment: @DougCoburn Not really. I didn't get the same error as before though. Instead of getting the error that the "tweepy" module wasn't found I got the error that the "queue" module wasn't found which is pretty weird since I've never really used the "queue" module.

Comment: The docs say the dependencies _should_ be found automatically. Perhaps `tweepy` depends on `queue`?  Looks like you are making progress, add `queue` to your package list as well.

Comment: @DougCoburn Yes it did! Thanks a lot for the help!!!!!

Comment: I'm glad it helped. I posted it as an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sometimes automatic dependency detection doesn't work.  Add missing package dependencies to your build_exe options in your setup.py

```
# Add tweepy, queue here
packages = ["idna", "tweepy", "queue"]
options = {
    'build_exe': {
        'packages':packages,
    },
}
```